# Getting substrings between '@' and ';' and before '@'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column `Amort` with each row containing string values like `3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Jun 30, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Sep 30, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Dec 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2021` in each row and I want to create columns associated with each year that contains the summed values of the floats associated with each year. So for the string above it would be 3,312.50 * 4 for the newly created column `Amort_2020`. But I've realized that there are some values in `Amort` that are like `0.64 @ Mar 31, 2020; 0.64 @ Jun 30, 2020; 0.64 @ Sep 30, 2020; 0.63 @ Dec 31, 2020; 0.64 @ Mar 31, 2021; 238.75 @ Jul 31, 2021` so my initial code below, which I was hoping to build on, isn't working. I wonder if theres a better way to do what Im trying to do. I looked into using `re` but couldn't think of a good way to do this.

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if df['Amort'].iloc[i] is not None:
        l = []
        no_periods = (str(df['Amort'].iloc[i])).count('2020') ##for summation
        temp = (df['Amort'].iloc[i]).replace("@", "") 
        temp = temp.replace(",", "") ###so that I can convert to float
        for k in range(no_periods):
            l.append(float(temp[:8]))
        df['Amort_2020'].iloc[i] = sum(l)
```

Edit:

Adding in the `df['Amort']` column:

```
0    3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Jun 30, 20...
1    1,137.50 @ Jun 17, 2020; 1,137.50 @ Sep 17, 20...
2    394.51 @ Jun 07, 2020; 394.50 @ Sep 07, 2020; ...
3    395.72 @ Jun 07, 2020; 395.73 @ Sep 07, 2020; ...
4    448.86 @ Jun 07, 2020; 448.87 @ Sep 07, 2020; ...
Name: Amort, dtype: object
```

Expected Output:
For 2020
`df['Amort_2020']`:

```
0    13250
1    3412.5
2    1183.53
```

And so, on for each year. Row0 contains `3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Jun 30, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Sep 30, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Dec 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2021` and because I want to sum up the float values associated with each year, for 2020 there are 4 such 3312.5 values,so it would be 3312.5*4 = 13250. The first row having the float multiplied by 4 and the rows 1 and 2 having the float multiplied by 3, as there are only 3 occurrences of 2020

Comment: can you add in the sample data and your expected output? I cna't tell if each row has multiple values delimited by `'@'` but it seems to be the case. if you can just `print(df.head(5))` and paste it here.

Comment: @Datanovice Sorry, should have added that. Just edited the question.

Comment: for row0 i can only see `3,312`, and the same value again - how did you get 13k? I assume there is some data mising from the sample?

Comment: @Datanovice Row0 contains `3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Jun 30, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Sep 30, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Dec 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2021` and because I want to sum up the float values associated with each year, for 2020 there are 4 such 3312.5 values,so it would be 3312.5*4 = 13250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `extractall`:

```
s = df.Amort.str.extractall('(?P<Amort>[\d,\.]+) \@ (?P<date>[\w ,]+);')

s['date'] = pd.to_datetime(s['date'])
s['Amort'] = s['Amort'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
s = s.reset_index('match',drop=True).set_index(s['date'].dt.year.rename('year'), append=True)

s.groupby(level=(0,1)).Amort.sum()
```

Output:

```
   year
0  2020    6625.00
1  2020    2275.00
2  2020     789.01
3  2020     791.45
4  2020     897.73
Name: Amort, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The dataframe seems to come out as  year Amort date
0 2020 3312.5 3/31/2020
0 2020 3312.5 6/30/2020
0 2020 3312.5 9/30/2020
0 2020 3312.5 12/31/2020
0 2021 3312.5 3/31/2021
0 2021 3312.5 6/30/2021
0 2021 3312.5 9/30/2021
0 2021 3312.5 12/31/2021
0 2022 3312.5 3/31/2022
for me, and not in the same format that you have given.

Comment: This output is from the excerpt of you sample data. since it is not complete ( some parts are cut off), your output may differ.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to do the job but for some reason skips the last substring every time. For example, for the second row it skips `1,069,937.50 @ Nov 30, 2026`. For the second it skips `424,287.50 @ Jan 17, 2027` and so on. Im not too sure why this is

Comment: That's because the `extractall` requires a `;` after the dates. You can fix it by `s = df.Amort.add(';').str.extractall(...)` instead.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess:

1. Initialize `df`

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Amort': {0: '3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Jun 30, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Sep 30, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Dec 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2021',
  1: '0.64 @ Mar 31, 2020; 0.64 @ Jun 30, 2020; 0.64 @ Sep 30, 2020; 0.63 @ Dec 31, 2020; 0.64 @ Mar 31, 2021; 238.75 @ Jul 31, 2021',
  2: '394.51 @ Jun 07, 2020; 394.50 @ Sep 07, 2020;'}})

>>> print(df)
                                               Amort
0  3,312.50 @ Mar 31, 2020; 3,312.50 @ Jun 30, 20...
1  0.64 @ Mar 31, 2020; 0.64 @ Jun 30, 2020; 0.64...
2      394.51 @ Jun 07, 2020; 394.50 @ Sep 07, 2020;
```

2. Define how to parse one row:

```
import re 
from collections import defaultdict 
def parse_amort(amort): 
    records = defaultdict(list) 
    for record in amort.split(";"): 
        if record.strip(): 
            amount, _, year = [s.strip() for s in re.split(r"@|, ", record)] 
            records[year].append(float(amount.replace(",", "")))  
    return records
```

3. Aggregate:

```
>>> df.Amort.apply(parse_amort)  \
            .apply(pd.Series)  \
            .fillna(0)  \
            .applymap(lambda l: sum(l) if isinstance(l, list) else 0)  \
            .add_prefix("Amort_")

   Amort_2020  Amort_2021
0    13250.00     3312.50
1        2.55      239.39
2      789.01        0.00
```

Comment: For whatever reason the final dataframe `df` doesnt contain `Amort_2020` or any columns like `Amort_`

Comment: I don’t understand your comment. You could assign step 3’s result into a new variable, say df2, and it would have the result required.